# Laravel Sail: could not find driver (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE') --- Mac

Tags: php, docker, laravel-8, laravel-sail

I just recently replaced my macbook.  I setup the previous project I was working on.  Unfortunately I encountered this error.

```
  could not find driver (SQL: SHOW FULL TABLES WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:712
    708▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    709▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    710▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    711▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 712▕             throw new QueryException(
    713▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    714▕             );
    715▕         }
    716▕     }
```

I'm using laravel/sail so all services are defined on `docker-compose.yml`.

All services are running properly without any errors via command `$ sail up -d`.

I can even connect to mysql service using TablePlus App.

Is there any new config I might have missed?

I tried checking DB connection using `tinker` and here is the output (no connection error found).

```
>>> DB::connection();
=> Illuminate\Database\MySqlConnection {#525}
>>>
```

Answer (score 2):

I have the same issue using the new Mac (Apple M1 Max), This is how I solve it.

```
// docker-compose.yml file

I commented out this line and it worked.

services:
  mariadb:
    # MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: "%"
```

when you run the migration, in the .env file modify the variable DB_HOST pointing to 127.0.0.1, once the migration is finished, put back the service name DB_HOST=mariadb. In my case I am using mariadb.

Hope this help.

Comment: Tried this, but it does not work - same error. Also `MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: %` allows access from all hosts - wildcard, so commenting it out will not help.

Answer (score 2):

It is simple really. Just prefix `artisan` with `sail`.

With using sail you are using containers and DB_HOST is set to internal host `mysql` which is not defined on host.

```sh
sail artisan migrate

## instead of: php artisan migrate
```

Also, all other common commands work:

- `sail artisan migrate`
- `sail php --version`
- `sail composer require some/lib`
- `sail npm run prod`

You should use `./vendor/bin/sail` if you don't have shell alias setup.

Comment: Thank you, also I needed to specify path to sail. So for me this works: `vendor/bin/sail artisan:migrate`

Comment: Yes. I have an alias in shell for this. I will update my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 20.04, go to the terminal then type:

```
sudo apt update

sudo apt install php8.1-mysql
```

Take note of the PHP Version that you are using and replace it on the command as necessary.

Hope it works for you. It did for me.